# C++ "triangle" (and not diamond) inheritance

Tags: c++, design-patterns, generic-programming, virtual-inheritance

(I searched and read thru the Diamond- and virtual-inheritance questions here, but could not find an answer. My thinking is that this situation is a little unusual, and I am willing to entertain the ideas that my requirements are somewhat off. On the other hand, I think this should be doable in a "nice" way.)

The situation and the requirements:

I have a C++ class library over which I have no control, and which I cannot change. It defines a `Window` class. The `Window` class has a protected member (say: `handle`), not otherwise accessible, that derived classes are meant to use. `Window` defines hundreds (well, a very large number...) of methods which I don't care to re-implement by delegating (in a decorator, say).

I want to add functionality to `Window`, so that derived classes (which I write; say `LogWindow`) automatically have. An example of such functionality is the ability to snap windows to each other. In order to implement this I need access to `Window`'s protected `handle` member.

For my real-life purpose this is enough, and the solution is simple: derive `SnappableWindow` from `Window`, and derive all my `Window`-derived classes (`LogWindow` in this example) from `SnappableWindow`.

However, what I would *really* want, and is prettier IMHO, is:

1. The ability to have this "Snappable" functionality as a standalone piece of code, which I can choose to "plug into" any other `Window`-derived class, or not.
2. The ability to extend this notion to other functionalities as well, for example the ability to minimize windows. So I could have a `Window`-derived class, with or without the "Snappable" ability, and with or without the "Minimizable" ability.
3. The implementations of "SnappableWindow" and "MinimizableWindow" both need access to `Window`'s `handle` protected member.
4. I would like "Snappable" and "Minimizable" to be part of the actual class declaration, so that my actual class (`LogWindow`) "is a" Window, "is a" SnappableWindow, and "is a" MinimizableWindow.

... and now to the question:

I get how I can do this with declaring `SnappableWindow` and `MinimizableWindow` as *not* deriving from `Window` but rather getting a `handle` in their constructor, and then deriving `LogWindow` from `Window` and from any combination of `SnappableWindow` and `MinimizableWindow`.

EDIT: `handle` is initialized, in `Window`, half-way thru LogWindow's constructor, after it has called `Window`'s init(). (and not half way thru `Window`'s constructor, as I've said before).

*However*, since `handle` is only initialized half way thru `LogWindow`'s constructor (after it has called `Window`'s `init()`) , I can't pass is to `SnappableWindow` and `MinimizableWindow` as part of `LogWindow`'s constructor initialization list. Rather, I would have to explicitly call some `init()` method on both, passing it the `handle`. And this, in each of my `Window`-derived classes. (`LogWindow`, `SearchWindow`, `PreferencesWindow`, etc.)

I am looking for a way to be able to do something like:

> class LogWindow : public Window, public SnappableWindow, public MinimizableWindow

... and not have to implement anything else inside `LogWindow`. I've fiddled with virtual inheritance, but can't quite come up with the solution.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Comment: At least on Windows, WTL is already pretty similar to what you seem to be trying to do. Since derived constructors only run *after* the base constructor has completed, the handle being initialized halfway through the base class' constructor shouldn't cause a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual inheritance should be able to handle this:

```
class SnappableWindow: virtual public Window

class MinimizableWindow: virtual public Window

class LogWindow: virtual public Window, public SnappableWindow, public MinimizableWindow
```

Note that a triangle is just a special case of a diamond!

```
Window
|  \  \---------------\
|   \                  \
|    SnappableWindow    MinimizableWindow
|   /                  /
|  /    /-------------/
LogWindow
```

Edit: here's a full example:

```
#include <iostream>
int get_handle() { static int handle = 0; return ++handle; }
struct Window {
    int handle;
    Window() : handle(get_handle()) { }
};
struct SnappableWindow: virtual public Window {
    SnappableWindow() { std::cout << "Snap! " << handle << std::endl; }
};
struct MinimizableWindow: virtual public Window {
    MinimizableWindow() { std::cout << "Mm! " << handle << std::endl; }
};
struct LogWindow: virtual public Window, public SnappableWindow, public MinimizableWindow {
    LogWindow() { std::cout << "Log! " << handle << std::endl; }
};
int main() {
    LogWindow lw;
    std::cout << "lw: " << lw.handle << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Snap! 1
Mm! 1
Log! 1
lw: 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. My problem was that I did not virtually-derive from Window in my LogWindow class. I *did* virtually derive SnappableWindow from Window. I think that pretty much answers it. Would you say this is "nice" and an accepted pattern? What are other/better ways of doing that?

Comment: @NitzanShaked virtual inheritance is absolutely fine; it's important to understand that the base class offset is applied at runtime so there is a small performance hit, balanced against improved binary compatibility.

Comment: Jordão's suggestion of using CRTP is more efficient at run-time as the base class offset is baked in at compile time; this is balanced by increased compilation and code size overhead. Both are accepted ways to achieve mixin-style functionality.

Comment: @curiousguy as you can see, in this scenario it enables coding functionality as mixins. There may be other situations where it is useful.

Comment: I meant: what is the difference between triangle and diamond? What does triangle that diamond does not?

Comment: @curiousguy it allows inheriting directly from a virtual base class as well as through an intermediate base class.

Comment: "_inheriting directly from a virtual base class_" Yes. But I still don't understand **why you would need to do that**, as we are talking about public virtual inheritance (I understand why you would do that if the other inheritance was private or protected virtual). Can you show one case where this direct inheritance changes something?

Comment: @curiousguy it seems pretty clear in this example (`Window`, `SnappableWindow` etc.) that triangle inheritance while perhaps not strictly necessary does model well the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You could use traits for that, but unfortunately they can't access protected members. You can do it if you create an intermediate class that exposes the protected member. See if it makes sense:

```
struct Window {
protected:
    int handle;
};
struct BaseWindow : public Window {
    int get_handle() { return handle; }
};
template <class TWindow>
struct Snappable {
    Snappable() { std::cout << "Snappable " << self()->get_handle() << std::endl; }
private:
    TWindow *const self() {
        return static_cast<TWindow*>(this);
    }
};
template <class TWindow>
struct Minimizable {
    Minimizable() { std::cout << "Minimizable " << self()->get_handle() << std::endl; }
private:
    TWindow *const self() {
        return static_cast<TWindow*>(this);
    }
};
struct LogWindow: public BaseWindow, public Snappable<LogWindow>, public Minimizable<LogWindow> {
};
```

Look [here](http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html) for an interesting architectural style that uses traits.

Comment: This pattern - templating on the derived class - is known as the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern or CRTP for short.

Comment: @ecatmur: indeed it is! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bit confusing... If the handle is initialized as part of the `Window` constructor, then it will be available after `Window` constructor completes in the initializer list:

```
class Window {
protected:
   int handle;
   Window() { handle = 5; }
};
struct Snappable {
   int hdl;
   Snappable( int handle ) : handle(handle) {}
};
struct MyWindow : Window, Snappable {       // Order matters here!
   MyWindow() : Window(), Snappable( handle ) {}
};
int main() {
   MyWindow w;
   std::cout << w.hdl << std::endl;         // 5
}
```

It is important to note that the order of execution of the base constructors is that of the declaration in the class definition, not the sequence in the initializer list.

That being said, whether this is a good design or not is a different question.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in describing where "handle" is initialized. I edited the original question.